# Discord.py channel.edit doesn't do anything, and bot doesn't go past that line

Tags: discord, discord.py

So basically, I have a channel which name is the member count of my server. Now, whenever someone joins or leaves it will update the name to "Member count: guild.member_count". On_member_join is working fine, but on_member_remove calls when someone joins but it never finishes, even though the code for join and remove is basically the same

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print('on_member_remove called')
    count_channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    await count_channel.edit(name = 'Member count: {}'.format(count_channel.guild.member_count))
    print('on_member_remove finished')
```

In this one, on_member_remove finished never prints, and it all works perfectly when on_member_join
Code for on_member_join:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('on_member_joim called')
    count_channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    await count_channel.edit(name = 'Member count: {}'.format(count_channel.guild.member_count))
    print('on_member_join finished')
```

Answer (score 1):

Channels have recently been rate-limited. This has been announced in the official Discord development servers. You're not doing anything wrong.

Here's the announcement:[image]

Comment: Oh, so that's why my bot that i scripted few weeks ago acted like that when I run it today. Thank you